# Is there a way to declare a CodeSuggestion to be incomplete or informal?

Tags: rust, internals, diagnostics

While improving [clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy) lints, I was asked if it's possible to tell if a lint's suggestion can be spliced into the code directly ("change `X` to `Y`"), or if it is incomplete / informal and should be implemented manually ("consider renaming this variable").

Currently, clippy uses `span_suggestion(Span, &str)`, but I don't see a way to inform the compiler about the type of suggestion being made. Is there some (planned) API to do this?

Comment: I added some examples based on what I think you are asking; please change them if inappropriate. If the examples are correct, won't you always have the problem that there is human text embedded in the suggestion? For example, "change `X` to `Y`" would have to be parsed to ignore the "change" and "to" parts. This seems like a very different data structure than a string would be needed.

Comment: OK, I should probably clarify: `span_suggestion` gets a span to replace and the code to replace it. But sometimes we have only incomplete code, e.g. `if let Some(m) = too { .. }` where the `..` denotes the match arm.